# setting seed for random forest model in r , handeling test train factor level differece

Tags: r, random-forest, seed

I am running a `for` loop  for multiple data sets using random forest.
The data sets are all different.

The question is when I set seed for train set and test set splitting, should the numbers in set seed be different?.
A simple description for my code would be

```
for (j in 1:87255)   #(for loop for creating data set RF)
#~~~~
set.seed(1000)
intrain<-sample(1:nrow(RF),size=nrow(RF)*0.7)


train<-RF[intrain,]
test<-RF[-intrain,]

forest_m<-randomForest(route~.,data=train,localImp=TRUE)

prd_v<-predict(forest_m,newdata=test,type='class')
result[j]<-sum(prd_v==test$route)/nrow(test)*100  
} 

#(route is my objective)
```

The reason for my question is because for some data sets in the for loop 
the factor levels of test set and train set are different. I am assuming its because there are not enough data in those sets.

So my final question would be

1. Should I set new seeds in the for loop when I create test,train data sets
2. Would there be a benchmark for some data sets which I should dump away (not enough data?)

Comment: The answer is no, set the RNG seed only once at the beginning, never in a loop. Remove `set.seed` from the loop, put it at the start of the script. Like this all samples will be exactly the same.

Comment: `sum(prd_v==test$route)/nrow(test)*100` can be simplified to `mean(prd_v==test$route)*100`.